# Validar entre Mayúsculas y Minúsculas en Login C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Estoy realizando un Login en el cual solicito los campos "Usuario" y "Contraseña" todo funciona perfectamente con la excepción de que al introducir los datos de los dos campos mencionados anteriormente sin importar de que estos se encuentren en mayúsculas o minúsculas siempre los valida con la condición de que estén correctamente escritos y posteriormente da acceso al sistema, cuando lo que quiero es que al introducir los datos se realice una verificación entre mayúsculas y minúsculas en los campos de "Usuario" y "Contraseña".

Este es mi código.

```
    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Loguear(txtUsuario.Text, txtContra.Text);
    }

    public void Loguear(string Id, string contrasena)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = ClsConexion.ObtenerConexion();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Usuario, Cargo from Empleado where Usuario = @ID AND Contrasena = @Contrasena", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", Id);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Contrasena", contrasena);
        SqlDataAdapter adaptador = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable tabla = new DataTable();

        adaptador.Fill(tabla);

        if (tabla.Rows.Count == 1)
        {
            if (tabla.Rows[0][1].ToString() == "Gerente")
            {
                frmInicio inicio = new frmInicio();
                inicio.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else if (tabla.Rows[0][1].ToString() == "Mesero")
            {
                frmInicio inicio = new frmInicio();
                inicio.Show();
                inicio.mst1.Visible = false;
                inicio.mst2.Visible = false;
                inicio.mst3.Visible = true;
                inicio.mst4.Visible = false;
                inicio.mst5.Visible = true;
                inicio.mst6.Visible = false;

                this.Hide();

            }
            else if (tabla.Rows[0][1].ToString() == "Recepcionista")
            {
                frmInicio inicio = new frmInicio();
                inicio.Show();
                inicio.mst1.Visible = false;
                inicio.mst2.Visible = true;
                inicio.mst3.Visible = true;
                inicio.mst4.Visible = true;
                inicio.mst5.Visible = true;
                inicio.mst6.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Usuario no registrado, Intentelo de nuevo");
        }



    }
```

En este código también he agregado roles a los usuarios lo cual me funciona perfectamente el único inconveniente es el anteriormente mencionado, también he intentado activar "Case Sensitive" en los campos Usuario y Contraseña en el gestor de base de datos (SQL Server) pero el Login aun sigue sin identificar entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Create de la tabla "Empleado" sobre la que estoy trabajando.

```
   create table Empleado
   (ID int not null, Nombre Varchar(50) not null, Cargo Varchar(50) not null, Usuario Varchar(25) not null,
   Contrasena Varchar(25) not null, constraint pk_ID primary key (ID))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuand ejecutas la consulta deberias indicar si es key-sensistive o no, para eso se deberia cambiar el `Collation`, por defecto es insensitive

```
string query = @"SELECT Usuario, Cargo
                  FROM Empleado 
                  WHERE Usuario = @ID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
                     AND Contrasena = @Contrasena COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
```

[COLLATE (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Justo lo que estaba buscando, gracias por tu ayuda Leandro.